# Discrete Topology and Basis

Tags: general-topology

- Definition 1. If $X$ is any set, the collection of all subsets of $X$ is a topology on $X$, it is called the **discrete topology**.
- Definition 2. If $X$ is a set, **a base** for a topology $X$ is a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ such that 
  (1) For each $x \in X$ there is a least one base elements $B$ containing $x $.
  (2) If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two base elements $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$, then there is a
  base element $B_{3}$ containing $x$ such that $B_{3} \subset B_{1} \cap B_{2}$.
- If $\mathscr{B}$ satisfies these two conditions, then we define the topology $\mathcal{T}$ generated by $\mathcal{B}$ as
  follows: $ U \subseteq X$ is said to be open in $X$ (that is, to be an element of $\mathcal{T}$) iff for
  each $x \in U$, there is a base element $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$ and $B \subseteq U$. Note that
  each base element is itself an element of $\mathcal{T}$.

Example. If $X$ is any set, the collection of all one-point subsets of $X$ is a basis for the discrete topology on $X$.

My Attempt. Let $X=\left\{a,b\right\}$. Then, $T=P(X)=\left\{\emptyset,\left\{a\right\},\left\{b\right\},X\right\}$ is the discrete topology on $X$ and by the previous example the elements $\{\left\{a\right\},\left\{b\right\}\}$ is a base for $T$ on $X$.

May you check my attempt? Thanks...

Comment: A basis of $T$ is a *subcollection* of $T$ (not an element of $T$).

Comment: You haven't shown the example, you've written out a simple special case of it but haven't proved anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is any set and we have the collection $\mathcal{B}=\{\{x\}: x \in X\}$ of singleton sets. It fulfills the conditions of being a base, as can easily be checked (the intersection condition is trivial, as the elements of the base are pairwise disjoint).

Now if $O$ is any subset of $X$, then for any $x \in X$ we have that we have a $B \in \mathcal{B}$, namely $B=\{x\}$, such that $x \in B \subseteq O$ (of course $\{x\} \subseteq O$ is just saying exactly that $x \in O$) and so $O$ is open in the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$. As $O \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ was arbitary, this topology is just the whole power set, hence the discrete topology.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prove the result with an example. Take any non-empty set $X$ and consider the collection of all subsets of $X$. This **the** discrete topology on $X$. Then verify that  the collection of all singleton sets satisfies the properties required for a  basis. This is quite straightforward. (Let me know if you get stuck).

Comment: Can you give a basis (or bases) for $T$? ($T$ as in my example)

Comment: Your example is correct.

Comment: $P(X)$ is a basis for $T$ in my example, right?

Comment: @PozcuKushimotoStreet Yes, it is.